# Loop through array of arrays in D3

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have an array of x objects each with an array of y objects like so:

```
var data = [
    { name: '1', data: [1,2,3] },
    { name: '2', data: [1,2,3] }
]
```

Is there a way to chain d3 functions in order to iterate through each data[x] and each data[x][y]?

I thought something like this would have helped, but not apparently:

```
var svg = d3.selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .selectAll('rect') /* This might be made up, but it makes sense to me :)*/
    .data(data, function (d, i) {
        return data[i].data;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
```

Thanks

Comment: The only other alternative I have right now is using a for loop, which works fine, just hoping there is a smarter way

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about something along these lines : //untested

```
var svg = d3.selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .selectAll('rect') /* This might be made up, but it makes sense to me :)*/
    //.data(data, function (d, i) {
    //   return data[i].data;
    //})
    //.enter()
    //.append('rect')
    .each(function(d){
    d3.select(this).selectAll('rect').data(d.data).append('rect')//and so on
    })
```

EDIT :

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/reko91/58WJE/34/

```js
var data = [
    { name: '1', data: [1,2,3] },
    { name: '2', data: [1,2,3] }
]

var colourScale = ['red','blue','yellow']
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 1000).attr('height', 1000);
svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
  .enter().append('g')
    .each(function(d,i){
        d3.select(this).selectAll('rect')
        .data(d.data)
      .enter().append('rect')
        .attr('x', function(d,j) { return j*100; })
        .attr('y', function() { return i*100; })
        .attr('width', function() { return 90; })
        .attr('height', function() { return 90; })
        .attr('fill', function(d,j) { console.log(d); return colourScale[j]; })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks `each` function does the trick although it would have to be moved to `... append('g').each` as `rect` is not available yet to be used

Comment: Edited answer again. Works fine now, thats okay right ?

Comment: Yip :) I do think it was fine the first time

Comment: yeah the rects were appending fine the first time but you couldnt see them so I had to position them correctly :)

Answer (score 8):

While an explicit `.each` loop works, the **d3** approved way to do this is with a [nested selection](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/):

```js
var data = [
    { name: '1', data: [1,2,3] },
    { name: '2', data: [1,2,3] }
]

var colourScale = ['red','blue','yellow']
var colourScale2 = ['yellow','pink','black']
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 1000).attr('height', 1000);
svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
  .enter().append('g')
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(function(d){
    return d.data;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', function(d,i) { return i*100; })
  .attr('y', function(d,i,j) { return j*100; })
  .attr('width', function() { return 90; })
  .attr('height', function() { return 90; })
  .attr('fill', function(d,i) { return colourScale2[i]; })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question about "**How to nest elements with nested data in d3.js**", which I also encounter recently. (also thinking a robust way to deal with these scenario)

These articles wrote by Mike Bostock related to the issue:
  1. [How selection work](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/)
  - let you know how data binding to selection
 2. [Nested Selection](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/)
  - knowing how selection chaining function really happen under the hood

Here is how I deal with this problem when using svg (canvas may have other ways).

**First**, the mindset of D3 is 'Data-driven Document'. To deal with nested data, you have to create nested elements in SVG.(you will find that your design on data structure really matter, it reflect viz result). < g >  element(g stand for grouping) in SVG can solve this problems, which created for grouping elements under svg like < path > , < rect >, < circle >. You cannot nested element under path, rect, circle but g or svg.

**Second**, you need to imagine the nested structure on document. Here for example:

```
<svg>
    <g class="layer1">
        <g class="layer2">
            <rect x="0" y="1" class='layer2'></rect>
        </g>
        <g class="layer2">
            <rect x="1" y="1" class='layer2'></rect>
        </g>
        <g class="layer2">
            <rect x="2" y="1" class='layer2'></rect>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g class="layer1">
        <g class="layer2">
            <rect x="0" y="2" class='layer2'></rect>
        </g>
        <g class="layer2">
            <rect x="1" y="2" class='layer2'></rect>
        </g>
        <g class="layer2">
            <rect x="2" y="2" class='layer2'></rect>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**Third**, using the [d3.collection](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md) and [d3.select](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection) to match the data and document. Better to read the d3 doc, in case the change of syntax under different d3 version. The d3.v4 and v3 had quite a difference under the data join, select, data index, data manipulation and now 2018/02 the d3 go into v5.
Here re-frame the question code.

```
const svg = d3.select('body')
              .append('svg')
              .attr('width', 1000)
              .attr('height', 1000);
```

We got the **svg**, which is d3.select obj, contain the svg element.

```
const layer1 = svg.selectAll('g.layer1')
                  .data(data)
                  .enter()
                  .append('g')
                  .classed('layer1', true);
```

We got the **layer1**, which created by using selectAll and enter our data with .data() and enter(), also append the g element according to the object num of data, which is 2 in this scenario

```
const layer2 = layer1.selectAll('g.layer2')
                     .data((d,i,j)=>{
                        let num = d3.entries(j)[i].key
                        return d.data.map((d)=> [d,num])
                                     })
                     .enter()
                     .append('g')
                     .classed('layer2', true);
```

We got the **layer2** element, leveraging the hierarchical selection ability of d3.selection in chaining function and use the d3.enteries to give the layer1 index pass to layer2 (since v4, the data key function will no longer keep parent index, so this is the alternative method i figure out. refer to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233003/d3-js-v4-how-to-access-parent-groups-datum-index)). the d3.enteries give the key to each element in array, we use it to store the parent index

```
layer2.append('rect')
      .attr('x', (d,i)=> i*60)
      .attr('y', (d,i)=> d[1]*60)
      .attr('width', 50)
      .attr('height', 50)
      .attr('fill', 'blue');
```

Then, Using **layer2** element,  we can append rect element according to the array in data.data with the index information of each data element .By the way, in this solution, we let each element in data.data carry the parent index.

So the result can be following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDxT5.png)

demo on Observable: 
https://beta.observablehq.com/@weitinglin/simple-case-01-nested-data-with-nested-selection