# d3.js v4: How to access parent group's datum index?

Tags: d3.js

The description of the `selection.data` function includes an example with multiple groups ([link](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data)) where a two-dimensional array is turned into an HTML table.

In d3.js v3, for lower dimensions, the accessor functions included a third argument which was the index of the parent group's datum:

```
td.text(function(d,i,j) {
  return "Row: " + j;
});
```

In v4, this `j` argument has been replaced by the selection's NodeList. How do I access the parent group's datum index now?

Answer (score 19):

Well, sometimes an answer doesn't provide a *solution*, because the solution may not exist. This seems to be the case.

According to Bostock:

> I’ve merged the new bilevel selection implementation into master and also simplified how parents are tracked by using a parallel parents array.
>
> A nice property of this new approach is that selection.data can
>   evaluate the values function in exactly the same manner as other
>   selection functions: the values function gets passed {d, i, nodes}
>   where this is the parent node, d is the parent datum, i is the parent
>   (group) index, and nodes is the array of parent nodes (one per group).
>   Also, the parents array can be reused by subselections that do not
>   regroup the selection, such as selection.select, since the parents
>   array is immutable.
>
> This change restricts functionality—in the sense that you ***cannot***
>   access the parent node from within a selection function, nor the
>   parent data, ***nor the group index*** — but I believe this is ultimately A
>   Good Thing because it encourages simpler code.

(emphasis mine)

Here's the link: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/47

So, it's not possible to get the index of the parent's group using `selection` (the parent's group index can be retrieved using `selection.data`, as this snippet bellow shows).

```js
var testData = [
[
  {x: 1, y: 40},
  {x: 2, y: 43},
  {x: 3, y: 12},
  {x: 6, y: 23}
], [
  {x: 1, y: 12},
  {x: 4, y: 18},
  {x: 5, y: 73},
  {x: 6, y: 27}
], [
  {x: 1, y: 60},
  {x: 2, y: 49},
  {x: 3, y: 16},
  {x: 6, y: 20}
 ] 
];

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 300);
  
var g = svg.selectAll(".groups")
    .data(testData)
    .enter()
    .append("g");
    
var rects = g.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d, i , j) { console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(d), "\nIndex: " + JSON.stringify(i), "\nNode: " + JSON.stringify(j)); return d})
    .enter()
    .append("rect");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I hadn't seen that issue so thanks for pointing it out. Using `.each()` to circumvent this restriction would make my code quite ugly but I guess at this point, there's no other way.

Comment: But how do you the index into 'someFunc' in `.append("rect").on("click", someFunc)`

Answer (score 12):

My workaround is somewhat similar to [Dinesh Rajan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39876215/2898738)'s, assuming the parent index is needed for attribute `someAttr` of `g.nestedElt`:

**v3**:

```
svg.selectAll(".someClass")
    .data(nestedData)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
    .attr("class", "someClass")
  .selectAll(".nestedElt")
    .data(Object)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
    .attr("class", "nestedElt")
    .attr("someAttr", function(d, i, j) {

    });
```

**v4**:

```
svg.selectAll(".someClass")
    .data(nestedData)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
    .attr("class", "someClass")
    .attr("data-index", function(d, i) { return i; }) // make parent index available from DOM
  .selectAll(".nestedElt")
    .data(Object)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
    .attr("class", "nestedElt")
    .attr("someAttr", function(d, i) {
      var j = +this.parentNode.getAttribute("data-index");
    });
```

Comment: Are there any form to access parent when using arrow operators? I.e.,.attr("someAttr", (d, i) => **???**)

Answer (score 4):

I ended up defining an external variable "j" and then increment it whenever "i" is 0

example **V3** snippet below.

```
rowcols.enter().append("rect")
 .attr("x", function (d, i, j) { return CalcXPos(d, j); })
 .attr("fill", function (d, i, j) { return GetColor(d, j); })
```

and in **V4**, code converted as below.

```
var j = -1;
rowcols.enter().append("rect") 
 .attr("x", function (d, i) { if (i == 0) { j++ }; return CalcXPos(d, j); })
 .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return GetColor(d, j); })
```

Comment: I think this only works if new rows are appended to the end of the table. If a row is inserted in the middle, it will receive the wrong "j" index. (This code also assumes a specific order in which d3.js processes the nodes. Since this is order is not documented anywhere, I'd be hesitant to use it.)

Comment: agree.. this is more or less a "hacky" way... guess will do if needing a quick and dirty conversion

Answer (score 2):

If `j` is the nodeList...

- `j[i]` is the current node *(eg. the td element)*,
- `j[i].parentNode` is the **level-1 parent** *(eg. the row element)*,
- `j[i].parentNode.parentNode` is the **level-2 parent** *(eg. the table element)*,
- `j[i].parentNode.parentNode.childNodes` is the **array of level-1 parents** *(eg. array of row elements)* including the original parent.

**So the question is, what is the index of the parent (the row) with respect to it's parent (the table)?**

We can find this using `Array.prototype.indexOf` like so...

```
k = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(j[i].parentNode.parentNode.childNodes,j[i].parentNode);
```

You can see in the snippet below that the row is printed in each `td` cell when `k` is returned.

```js
var testData = [
[
  {x: 1, y: 1},
  {x: 1, y: 2},
  {x: 1, y: 3},
  {x: 1, y: 4}
], [
  {x: 2, y: 1},
  {x: 2, y: 2},
  {x: 2, y: 3},
  {x: 2, y: 4}
], [
  {x: 3, y: 4},
  {x: 3, y: 4},
  {x: 3, y: 4},
  {x: 3, y: 4}
 ]
];

var tableData =
  d3.select('body').selectAll('table')
    .data([testData]);

var tables =
  tableData.enter()
  .append('table');

var rowData =
  tables.selectAll('table')
    .data(function(d,i,j){
      return d;
    });

var rows =
  rowData.enter()
  .append('tr');

var eleData =
  rows.selectAll('tr')
    .data(function(d,i,j){
      return d;
    });

var ele =
  eleData.enter()
  .append('td')
    .text(function(d,i,j){
      var k = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(j[i].parentNode.parentNode.childNodes,j[i].parentNode);
      return k;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**Reservations**

This approach is using DOM order as a proxy for data index. In many cases, I think this is a viable band-aid solution if this is no longer possible in D3 (as reported in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38235820/5776618)).

Some extra effort in manipulating the DOM selection to match data might be needed. As an example, filtering `j[i].parentNode.parentNode.childNodes` for `<tr>` elements only in order to determine the row -- generally speaking the childNodes array may not match the selection and could contain extra elements/junk.

While this is not a cure-all, I think it should work or could be made to work in most cases, presuming there is some logical connection between DOM and data that can be leveraged which allows you to use DOM child index as a proxy for data index.

Comment: This is only giving me the position of the DOM node with respect to its parent DOM node. In some cases (like your example), it may be the right value but often enough, this will be wrong. What I need is the index into the data array that's bound to the DOM - in fact, that's why I'm using d3.js in the first place. As soon as my data array changes or when the parent node contains other child nodes, your method will fail.

Comment: Excellent points. I think in many cases this CAN work as a solution, but I agree with you that it is not an inherent solution as it's relying on using DOM index/order as a proxy for the data index. I wrote this answer as a possible work-around after reading @gerardo 's answer that the previous functionality may just not be there anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to use the `selection.each()` method. I don't think it's messy, but it did slow down the render on a large matrix. Note the following code assumes an existing `table` selection and a call to `update()`.

```
update(matrix) {
        var self = this;
        var tr = table.selectAll("tr").data(matrix);

        tr.exit().remove();

        tr.enter().append("tr");

        tr.each(addCells);

        function addCells(data, rowIndex) {
            var td = d3.select(this).selectAll("td")
                .data(function (d) {
                    return d;
                });
            td.exit().remove();

            td.enter().append("td");

            td.attr("class", function (d) {
                return d === 0 ? "dead" : "alive";
            });

            td.on("click", function(d,i){
                matrix[rowIndex][i] = d === 1 ? 0 : 1; // rowIndex now available for use in callback.                   
            });
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            update(getNewMatrix(matrix))
        }, 1000);
    },
```

Comment: I like this as it doesn't require you to wrap your data elements into objects to hold references to their parent, but instead uses closures to access the index. The speed penalty could be due to issuing a lot of selectAll/exit/enter commands on tables with many rows but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you want to do a nested selectiom, and your
data is some array where each element in turn
contains an array, let's say "values".  Then you 
have probably some code like this:

```
var aInnerSelection = oSelection.selectAll(".someClass") //
    .data(d.values) //
    ...
```

You can replace the array with the values by a new array, where
you cache the indices within the group.

```
var aInnerSelection = oSelection.selectAll(".someClass") //
    .data(function (d, i) {
        var aData = d.values.map(function mapValuesToIndexedValues(elem, index) {
                return {
                    outerIndex: i,
                    innerIndex: index,
                    datum: elem
                };
            })
            return aData;
    }, function (d, i) {
        return d.innerIndex;
    }) //
    ...
```

Assume your outer array looks like this:
[{name "X", values: ["A", "B"]}, {name "y", values: ["C", "D"]}
With the first approach, the nested selection brings you from here

```
                  d                                i
------------------------------------------------------------------
root dummy X      {name "X", values: ["A", "B"]}    0
     dummy Y      {name "Y", values: ["C", "D"]}    1
```

to here.

```
             d       i
------------------------------------------------------------------
root X  A    "A"     0
        B    "B"     1
     Y  C    "C"     2
        D    "D"     3
```

With the augmented array, you end up here instead:

```
             d                                              i
------------------------------------------------------------------
root X  A    {datum: "A", outerIndex: 0, innerIndex: 0}     0
        B    {datum: "B", outerIndex: 0, innerIndex: 1}     1
     Y  C    {datum: "C", outerIndex: 1, innerIndex: 0}     2
        D    {datum: "D", outerIndex: 1, innerIndex: 1}     3
```

So you have within the nested selections, in any function(d,i), all
information you need.

Comment: This is actually what I end up doing in most of my code now. I would have liked for d3.js to provide a way to access the index (as it used to) instead of having to wrap every value into an extra object. But since that is gone now, I guess we'll have to go with this solution ([@david004's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40100145/2046109) may be a good alternative).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet I crafter after re-remembering this usage of `.each` for nesting, I thought it may be useful to others who end up here. This examples creates two layers of circles, and the parent group index is used to determine the color of the circles - white for the circles in the first layer, and black for the circles in the top layer (only two layers in this case).

```
const nested = nest().key(layerValue).entries(data);

let layerGroups = g.selectAll('g.layer').data(nested);
layerGroups = layerGroups.enter().append('g').attr('class', 'layer')
  .merge(layerGroups);

layerGroups.each(function(layerEntry, j) {   
  const circles = select(this)
    .selectAll('circle').data(layerEntry.values);
  circles.enter().append('circle')
    .merge(circles)
      .attr('cx', d => xScale(xValue(d)))
      .attr('cy', d => yScale(yValue(d)))
      .attr('r', d => radiusScale(radiusValue(d)))
      .attr('fill', j === 0 ? 'white' : 'black'); // <---- Access parent index.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to embed this information in the data provided to d3js

```js
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
flattened_data = data.reduce((acc, v, i) => {
    v.forEach((d, j) => {
      data_item = { i, j, d };
      acc.push(data_item);
    });
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

Then you can access i, j and d from the data arg of the function

```js
td.text(function(d) {
  // Can access i, j and original data here
  return "Row: " + d.j;
});
```