# How to give same classes

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have svg element of `<circle>` inside `<g>`, and I want to give each circle tag a class like this:

```
 <g class="parent">
    <circle class="circle_0"></circle>
    <circle class="circle_0"></circle>
    <circle class="circle_0"></circle>
    <circle class="circle_0"></circle>
  </g>
  <g class="parent">
    <circle class="circle_1"></circle>
    <circle class="circle_1"></circle>
    <circle class="circle_1"></circle>
    <circle class="circle_1"></circle>
  </g>
  <g class="parent">
    <circle class="circle_2"></circle>
    <circle class="circle_2"></circle>
    <circle class="circle_2"></circle>
    <circle class="circle_2"></circle>
  </g>
```

the number after `circle_` comes from the order of its parent `<g>`, but each parent has the same class name.

I am creating them like this and right now, every `<circle>` has the same class:

```
var g = svg.append("g")
var parentElement = g.selectAll(".parent")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "parent");

parentElement.selectAll(".circle")
    .data(function(d,i) { return d; })
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circle")
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried?  On SO you are normally expected to try yourself and ask a question when you get stuck. If you have code that is not working, post that to your question.

Comment: On top of what @Paul said, I assume that you already have a code to create the groups and the circles, and your problem is only setting the classes... that being the case, please post your code.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau sorry about that. I just added the way I am creating it

Comment: Another important information: are you using d3 v3 or v4?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I am using v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using D3 v3 you can use the *third argument*, which is the parent's index, to set your classes:

```
.attr("class", function(d,i,p){
    return "class_" + p;
});
```

Check the snippet:

```js
var data = [[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]];
var svg = d3.select("body");
var g = svg.append("g")
var parentElement = g.selectAll(".parent")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "parent");

parentElement.selectAll(".circle")
    .data(function(d,i) { return d; })
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", function(d,i,p){
  console.log("circle_" + p);
  return "circle_" + p;
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

PS: this will **not** work on D3 v4 ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38235820/5768908)).

Comment: Thanks again Gerardo! wow that was easy. I did not even know that there is the 3rd argument.