# check if d3.select or d3.selectAll

Tags: d3.js

I have a method on a reusable chart that can be passed a selection and return a value if it is passed a `d3.select('#id')` selection or an array of values if it is passed a `d3.selectAll('.class')` selection.  I'm currently interrogating the passed argument with `context._groups[0] instanceof NodeList`, but it feels a little fragile using an undocumented property, as that may change in future versions.  Is there a more built in way of determining if a selection comes from `select` or `selectAll`?

`selection.size()` will not help here, as it only tells us the result of the selection, not how it was called.

EDIT:
Here's the context of the use.  I'm using Mike Bostock's [reusable chart pattern](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) and this instance includes a method for getting/setting a label for a donut.

To me, this API usage follows the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), as it's how I would expect the result to be returned.

```
var donut = APP.rotatingDonut();

// set label for one element
d3.select('#donut1.donut')
    .call(donut.label, 'Donut 1')

d3.select('#donut2.donut')
    .call(donut.label, 'Donut 2')

// set label for multiple elements
d3.selectAll('.donut.group-1')
    .call(donut.label, 'Group 1 Donuts')


// get label for one donut
var donutOneLabel = d3.select('#donut1').call(donut.label)
// donutOnelabel === 'Donut 1'

// get label for multiple donuts
var donutLables = d3.selectAll('.donut').call(donut.label)
// donutLabels === ['Donut 1', 'Donut 2', 'Group 1 Donuts', 'Group 1 Donuts']
```

and the internal method definition:

```
App.rotatingDonut = function() {

  var label = d3.local();

  function donut() {}

  donut.label = function(context, value) {
    var returnArray;
    var isList = context._groups[0] instanceof NodeList;

    if (typeof value === 'undefined' ) {

      // getter
      returnArray = context.nodes()
          .map(function (node) {return label.get(node);});

      return isList ? returnArray : returnArray[0];
    }

    // settter
    context.each(function() {label.set(this, value);});

    // allows method chaining
    return donut;
  };

  return donut
}
```

Comment: Very nice and interesting question. I wrote an answer which is not the answer you expect. If someone else proves me wrong, I'll happily delete it.

Comment: Just a curiosity: *why* are you doing this? Why don't simply pass a second argument to the function, informing the type of method? You see, this is a strong candidate for being a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I've updated my post to give full context.  The goal here is to find the "most d3-like" way of implementing this getter/setter method.  The "best" answer would be an example of d3 doing this same thing for one of it's methods.

Answer (score 2):

Well, sometimes a question here at S.O. simply doesn't have an answer (it has [happened before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38235820/5768908)).

That seems to be the case of this question of yours: *"Is there a more built in way of determining if a selection comes from select or selectAll?"*. Probably no.

To prove that, let's see the source code for `d3.select` and `d3.selectAll` (**important**: those are *not* `selection.select` and `selection.selectAll`, which are very different from each other).

First, [d3.select](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/select.js#L3):

```
export default function(selector) {
    return typeof selector === "string"
        ? new Selection([[document.querySelector(selector)]], [document.documentElement])
        : new Selection([[selector]], root);
}
```

Now, [d3.selectAll](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selectAll.js#L3):

```
export default function(selector) {
    return typeof selector === "string"
        ? new Selection([document.querySelectorAll(selector)], [document.documentElement])
        : new Selection([selector == null ? [] : selector], root);
}
```

As you can see, we have only **two** differences here:

1. `d3.selectAll` accepts `null`. That will not help you.
2. `d3.selectAll` uses `querySelectorAll`, while `d3.select` uses `querySelector`.

That second difference is the only one that suits you, as you know by now, since [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a **NodeList**. (emphasis mine)

And [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only...:

> Returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors.

Therefore, the undocumented (and hacky, since you are using `_groups`, which is not a good idea) `selection._groups[0] instanceof NodeList` you are using right now seems to be the only way to tell a selection created by `d3.select` from a selection created by `d3.selectAll`.