# Text and Rectangle not align

Tags: d3.js, svg

The following is the code of rectangle with text within.

[image]

The problem is that it can't seem to align. How to make them align more easily?

Here's the code I use:

I know I can adjust the `x` and `y` for rectangle and text, but a more organized way to make them align is probably to have one `g` for each rectangle and related text, and adjust their positions within the `g`? How to achieve that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.8/d3.min.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
<!--script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.9/d3.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script-->
<style>
    rect {
        stroke: #9A8B7A;
        stroke-width: 1px;
        fill: #CF7D1C;
        opacity:
    }
</style>
<body></body>
<script>
    var dataset = [[1,3,3,5,6,7],[3,5,8,3,2,6],[9,0,6,3,6,3],[3,4,4,5,6,8],[3,4,5,2,1,8]];

    var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500);
    var local = d3.local();


    svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .selectAll("text")
            .data(function(d, i) {

                local.set(this, i)
                return d;
            })
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(function(d, i, j) {
                return d;
            })
            .attr("x", function(d, i, j) {
                return (i * 20) + 40;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return (local.get(this) * 20) + 40;
            })
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", "20px");




    svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(dataset)//use top-level data to join g
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d, i) {//for each <g>, use the second-level data (return d) to join rect
                console.log(this);
                local.set(this, i);//this is the <g> parent
                return d;
            })
            .enter()
            .append("rect")

            .attr("x", function(d, i, j) {
                return (i * 20) + 40;

            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return (local.get(this) * 20) + 40;
            })
            .attr("width",20)
            .attr("height",20)
            .attr("fill-opacity",0.1)




</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution is just setting the [dominant-baseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline). This is a nice image with the possible values:

[image]

<sup>Source: http://bl.ocks.org/eweitnauer/7325338</sup>

So, in your case, just do:

```
.attr("dominant-baseline", "text-before-edge")
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var dataset = [
  [1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7],
  [3, 5, 8, 3, 2, 6],
  [9, 0, 6, 3, 6, 3],
  [3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8],
  [3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 8]
];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500);
var local = d3.local();

svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(dataset) //use top-level data to join g
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d, i) {
    local.set(this, i); //this is the <g> parent
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i, j) {
    return (i * 20) + 40;

  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return (local.get(this) * 20) + 40;
  })
  .attr("width", 20)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "tan")
  .attr("stroke", "dimgray")
  .attr("fill-opacity", 0.4);
  
  svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(function(d, i) {
    local.set(this, i)
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d, i, j) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d, i, j) {
    return (i * 20) + 40;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return (local.get(this) * 20) + 40;
  })
  .attr("dominant-baseline", "text-before-edge")
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", "20px");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have another following up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631532/placing-text-at-center-of-rectangle
Could help look into it?