# Simplest way to store 2d array in external file

Tags: d3.js

I need to populate a 2d array, e.g.,

```
var dataset = [[1,3,3,5,6,7],[3,5,8,3,2,6],[9,0,6,3,6,3],[3,4,4,5,6,8],[3,4,5,2,1,8]];
```

Where the information comes from external sources, while I have the control in the format to store them (csv,json etc., to be read by functions like `d3.csv`, `d3.json` etc.).

What are the simplest ways to store 2d array in external files, and to read in to populate the variable like `dataset` when doing d3 processing?

Comment: I edited your question, replacing "best" with "simplest" (still not the best option). "Best" is quite opinion-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using a CSV file, a TSV file, a XML file, a text file... However, I believe that the **simplest** way to store your array of arrays is just saving it (the way it is right now, no change, but without the semicolon of course) in a JSON file.

Therefore, if you ask what is the simplest way (and, if by *simplest*, you mean the way which requires less code to get the final result), JSON is by far the best choice.

Here is a plunker illustrating this (I can't use stack snippets to load JSON files), have a look at the console: https://plnkr.co/edit/2ksVXhnP8EFFHo8P1vrt?p=preview

The code is simply:

```
d3.json("data.json", function(data){
    console.log(data)
})
```

And the `data.json` file is just:

```
[
    [1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7],
    [3, 5, 8, 3, 2, 6],
    [9, 0, 6, 3, 6, 3],
    [3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8],
    [3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 8]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess it really depends on what "best way" means.  D3 offers a variety of ways to load in data: csv, tsv, json.  Since many APIs return JSON data these days, I like to stick to that format if I can.  Should you choose to go that way, you can use the following D3 function:

```
d3.json("path/to/file.json", function(dataset) {
  // Data is now in dataset 
  console.log(dataset);
});
```

But of course you can do the exact same thing with csv or tsv.

Comment: Note that you might need to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file) if you're developing in Chrome, or else you'll get an error preventing file access by files.

Comment: Or just set up a simple server like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)