# d3.js v4 / v5: How to access parent group's index for color schemes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm looking to make the following work:

```
.attr("fill", function (d, i, j) {
     return color(j)
```

Using j as the parent element's index worked fine in V3, but that was dropped in V4 according to [d3.js v4: How to access parent group's datum index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233003/d3-js-v4-how-to-access-parent-groups-datum-index).

I have a radial/radar/... chart, and the points on the axes are supposed to be colored in the same color as the areas are.

Here, it's fixed using "id", but I cant quite get that to work just yet - and was wondering if there is not a prettier way of working it anyway?
http://bl.ocks.org/mthh/7e17b680b35b83b49f1c22a3613bd89f

Cheers!